# Why are .anims so big?

Tags: unity, animation

I am in the process of recording dialogue via FaceCapX and an animation recorder script that checks for changes between frames and if there is one it saves the value of 52 blend shapes, as well as head transform rotation and position.

To my limited understanding, the file should be containing something like (int) frame + (double) blend shape value per frame.? Which would lead to something like:

in byte:
4 + (8 * 52 blend shapes) * 60 frames per second * 60 seconds = 1,497 MB per minute.

Anyway, I end up with 18 MB for roughly 15 seconds of recording.

What is missing in my calculation?
Is there a bug in unity .anims?

Comment: that comes to 21 kb per frame, sounds like they are recording each point in the rig and the blends will come later

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I experimented a little. I deleted all properties except the blend shapes and the file size doubled. I'm pretty sure, there is a bug within unity by now.

Comment: I assume you are using binary serialization of these files, yes? If not, it would make sense they are very large, and you should switch to binary serialization. If you are already using binary serialization, you could try switching to text serialization to see exactly what _is_ being serialized. Although you’d probably want to make a sample file with only a few frames of animation so you aren’t browsing through a gigantic text file in a text editor which is not designed to do so.